# Get GPS permission in class-A How to get class-A data in class-B

Tags: android

For example, I am currently working on a project. I get GPS authorization in classA. Now I want to get the latitude and longitude of classA in classB, but get 0 using (new A().getlatitude) and (A().getlongitude). ,what should I do.

In MainActivity I get GPS permission in Layout R.layout.activity_main, I want use MainActivity's GPS Latitude and Longitude value in other class(other Layout)(other class has no GPS permission), I have no idea

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I forgot to say my beginning home class(other class has no GPS permission)

new MainActivity().Latitude; also getvalue = 0

Comment: `new MainActivity()` You cannot use the new operator to create an activity instance. You should use an intent for that.

Comment: Classes or activities have no gps permission. Its the app that has gps permission. So what you suggest makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, you define the values in classA:

```
public static double latitude;
public static double longitude;
```

Then, you do whatever you need to do with these values.

To access it from classB, you do it like this for instance:

```
double whatever = classA.latitude;
```

Comment: @Override public void onLocationChanged（Location location）{ 
Latitude = location.getLatitude（）; //緯度Longitude = location.getLongitude（）; //經度}

Comment: this is my code, I declared public static double Latitude;
public static double Longitude; to getLatitude and getLongitude, but in other class declared classA.Latitude; Still get 0

Comment: Are you running your code on an emulator or physical device? If you're using the Android emulator, it explains why you get 0 for the GPS coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution but you can use SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

// In class A
prefs.edit().putString("latitude", String.valueOf(myLatitude)).apply();
prefs.edit().putString("latitude", String.valueOf(myLatitude)).apply();

// In class B
Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("latitude", "0.0"));
Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("longitude", "0.0"));
```